# SQL SUBSTRING in WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table numbers (number varchar(10));
insert into numbers (number) values
('1234123452'),
('5532003644'), 
('1122330505'),                                      
('1103220311'),                                     
('1103000011'),
('1103020012');
```

Query:-

```
SELECT * FROM numbers 
WHERE SUBSTRING(Number,1,4) = SUBSTRING(Number,5,8)
```

Result:-

> There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Expected Result**:

> 1234123452

Comment: Third paramete of `SUBSTRING` is Length. Try `SUBSTRING(Number,5,4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument to `SUBSTRING()` is the length, not the ending position. So it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers 
WHERE SUBSTRING(Number,1,4) = SUBSTRING(Number,5,4)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the solution I'll be accepting your answer after 10 mins...

Comment: Why I am getting the wrong result [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vog9exkpK235ngo523uVK1/1)? My expectation result is **1212121205**. (XY-XY-XY-XY)

Comment: Your second `=` should be `AND`.

Comment: If I use `AND` in the second one, it will also display: **5656848411**, but I just want  ***1212121205***. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vog9exkpK235ngo523uVK1/2. This time before sharing the link, please update the fiddle!

Comment: Then you want `SUBSTR(number, 1, 2) = SUBSTR(number, 3, 2) AND SUBSTR(number, 1, 2) = SUBSTR(number(5, 2) AND SUBSTR(number, 1, 2) = SUBSTR(number, 7, 2)`

Comment: You can't chain comparisons, you need to specify all 3 comparisons separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of `REGEXP_LIKE` here, assuming you are using MySQL 8+:

```
SELECT *
FROM numbers
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Number, '^(.{4})\\1';
```

The pattern `^(.{4})\\1` matches and captures the first four characters, then asserts that these same characters appear immediately afterward.

Comment: I am weak in the regex! Any best online tutorial? BTW please have a look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56919877/sql-substring-in-where-condition/#comment100382476_56919893)

Comment: I have provided a valid answer to your question.  A longer explanation of how regex works is out of scope for a single answer.

Comment: @Raja Go to www.regular-expression.info

Comment: `where number regexp '(.*([0-9])\2.*){4}'` this will result *XY-XY-XY-XY* at any place.